# Is there a way to create a copy of the default keymap configuration?

Tags: python, scripting, customization, shortcut

I'm trying to programmatically create a Key Configuration that is a copy of the Default configuration except all "S" and "O" mappings are swapped.
eg.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> -> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> -> <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>

I was able to swap the Key Mappings of the Default Key Configuration with the following code:

```
wm = bpy.context.window_manager
default = wm.keyconfigs['Blender'] # Default Key Configuration
for keymap in default.keymaps:
    for keymap_item in keymap.keymap_items:
        if keymap_item.type == 'O':
            keymap_item.type = 'S'
        elif keymap_item.type == 'S':
            keymap_item.type = 'O'
```

However, I cannot find a way to create a copy of the Default configuration, since making a new configuration ([`wm.keyconfigs.new()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_76_9/bpy.types.KeyConfigurations.html#bpy.types.KeyConfigurations.new)) doesn't actually copy the Defaults instead it just creates an empty Key Configuration where you cannot iterate over the `keymaps` (since they don't exist).

So, **is there a way to create a copy of the default configuration?**

Answer (score 1):

Holy smokes, this was miserable to figure out but this appears to work:

```
        import bpy

        wm = bpy.context.window_manager
        CopiedMap = wm.keyconfigs.new("CopiedMap")

        #Get list of default keymap items
        keymaps = wm.keyconfigs.default.keymaps.items()
        for i in keymaps:

            #Put default values in to new keymaps 
            CopiedMap.keymaps.new(i[1].name, space_type= i[1].space_type, 
                                  region_type=i[1].region_type) 

            #Get list of default keymap_items contained 
            #within the keymap 
            keymap_items = i[1].keymap_items.items()
            for j in keymap_items:

                #Put values in to new keymap_items
                CopiedMap.keymaps[i[1].name].keymap_items.new(j[1].idname, j[1].type, j[1].value, any=j[1].any, 
                                                              shift=j[1].shift, ctrl=j[1].ctrl, alt=j[1].alt, 
                                                              oskey=j[1].oskey, key_modifier=j[1].key_modifier)
```

I'm not a very good scripter so this is probably not a very good answer, but maybe it'll get you by until somebody better at this comes along. :)